# Unique successful combinations in knapsack

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have a simpler variation of knapsack.
I am only interested to find the unique members in an array which sum up to a given value.
Code is below:

```
public void process(int w){

    knaprecurse(arr.length-1,w);
}

private void knaprecurse(int n,int w){
    if(arr[n]>w)
        knaprecurse(n-1,w);

    if(arr[n]==w)
    {
    //add the unique members to a list
        targetlist.add(....);//how?
    }

    if(arr[n]<w){
        knaprecurse(n-1,w);
        knaprecurse(n-1,w-arr[n]);
    }
}
```

How do I record each unique combination which adds up to the value?

Comment: What does unique member exactly mean?

Comment: This seems to be reducible to [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which asks whether there any subset that sums to the given value.

Comment: The details of how to declare and manage a set of sets of integers, the required result type, depends on the language. I suggest adding a language tag.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You are right indeed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Subset-sum_problem. Note that this is a NP Complete problem. As such, counting the solutions will be computationally expensive past a certain number of items.

Comment: I actually wrote the reduction comment the wrong way round. Subset-sum is reducible to this problem by asking whether the number of combinations is at least one, which proves this problem NP-Hard.